# using handlebars bindAttr for checkbox

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars in a backbone.js rails app, and I have a Boolean field I'm populating with a checkbox.

When I load the edit page, the form is populated with the contents from the server JSON something like

```
{id:3,user:'test',checkbox:1}
```

now in my handlebar form, I want to show that the checkbox is 1.

```
< input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" {{#if checkbox}} {{bindAttr checkbox checked="isSelected"}}{{/if}} >
```

but this isn't returning the checked checkbox. I'd really like to just be able to say `if checkbox==1`, but I don't see how I can do that with handlebars.

Anysuggestions??

Answer (score 9):

What you would usually do, is using a Boolean in the 'model'.

```
{
    isChecked: true
}
```

and then

```
<input type="checkbox" {{bindAttr checked="isChecked"}}>
```

If the Boolean is true, it will render the `checked` property, and if the Boolean is false, it would omit the property. So if `isChecked` is true, then Handlebars would output

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

and if `isChecked` were false, we would get

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

Which is what we want!

Comment: for a two-way binding of the element's "checked" property to the controller/context (so that the controller/context is updated when the checkbox is checked) you can use an input helper: `{{ input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked value="1" data-unchecked-value="0" }}`
(but since 'data-unchecked-value' isn't supported by ember input helpers, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894335 )

Answer (score 9):

I also wrote a helper to do this. It doesn't use backbone.js, so may be an alternative for some:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checked', function(currentValue) {
    return currentValue == '1' ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
});
```

Usage example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxExample" id="cbxExample" {{checked cbxExample}}/>
```

Would tick a checkbox if the supplied JSON was:

```
{"cbxExample" : "1"}
```

Resulting in:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxExample" id="cbxExample" checked="checked" />
```

[my first post - hope that's helpful!]

Comment: You probably want to use a triple `{` around so that the `"` doesn't get escaped. with `{{checked cbxExample}}` the output will actually be `checked=&quot;checked&quot;` in your code. With `{{{checked cbxExample}}}`, then we get the correct output (`checked="checked"`).

Comment: This helped me deal with JSON having...
checked: "true" or "false" -- as strings
`return currentValue == 'true' ? 'checked' : '';`