# add a name attribute to a Ember.TextField?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Its been a long day and this is probably extemely simple but how do i add a name attribute to a Ember.TextField ?

I want to do something like this :

```
{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="your_name" placeholder="Your name" name="your_name"}}
```

This works with the placeholder but ignores the name.

Any ideas ??

thanks
Rick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name attribute is not bound by default, [see](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_field.js#L23)

As a workaround, you could create your own `TextField`, see http://jsfiddle.net/fkPzr/

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        // get attributeBindings and add 'name'
        var attributeBindings = this.get('attributeBindings');
        attributeBindings.pushObject('name');
        this.set('attributeBindings', attributeBindings);
    }
});
```

---

**​UPDATE**:

Since `attributeBindings` is declared as a [concatenated property](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L59)* the TextField can be simplified, see http://jsfiddle.net/cRhcg/:

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['name']
});
```

*a concatenated property does not override the property of an extended object but the existing values from the super object are concatenated. Makes sense? Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/zwfH4/)

Comment: thanks a lot pangratz.   Surley this should be default as you need name for testing ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because Ember.TextField does not expose this a attribute binding.

From Ember.TextField

```
attributeBindings: ['type', 'value', 'size'],
```

plus the ones from the mixin:

```
attributeBindings: ['placeholder', 'disabled', 'maxlength'],
```

To bind the name property, create an own subclass that adds 'name' to the attribute bindings

Comment: Sorry, @pangratz was faster :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. **However, I would suggest not doing this. The idea behind ember is to keep information such as this out of the DOM.**

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['name']
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simple want to have the option to specify a name attribute you can do it using attributeBindings.

```
{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="your_name" placeholder="Your name" attributeBindings="name" name="your_name"}}
```

Comment: setting `attributeBindings` via Handlebars is not allowed, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/c524f3e91d3c3dfa0b9a95d0c8fbf4dc199b4ac3/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/view.js#L44-48